# selection sort inconsistency in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

I've been trying to write a selection sort program in Java and think (after looking through other forums) that I have the code right. Curretnly it's

```
public class SelectionSort {
    
    public static int[] selectionSort(int[] numbers) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int currentMin = i;
            for(int k = i+1; k < numbers.length; k++) {
                if (numbers[k] < numbers[currentMin]) {
                    currentMin = k;
                
                    if(currentMin != i) {
                        int placeholder = numbers[i];
                        numbers[i] = numbers[currentMin];
                        numbers[currentMin] = placeholder;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

When I run through 3 sample arrays, some of them work and some don't. I've incldued the before and after arrays below:

> [5, 2, 7, 6, 8, 1, 5]
>
> [1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8] (correct order)
>
> [5, 2, 4, 0, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0, 7, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 0, 8, 2, 7, 6, 3, 9, 0]
>
> [3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9] (wrong order)
>
> [8, 5, 7, 6, 2, 7, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 9]
>
> [2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9] (wrong order)

When I shift the braces around so  they're like so:

```
public class SelectionSort {

public static int[] selectionSort(int[] numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int currentMin = i;
            for(int k = i+1; k < numbers.length; k++) {
                if (numbers[k] < numbers[currentMin]) {
                    currentMin = k;
                    }
                
                    if(currentMin != i) {
                        int placeholder = numbers[i];
                        numbers[i] = numbers[currentMin];
                        numbers[currentMin] = placeholder;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

I get these results

> [5, 2, 7, 6, 8, 1, 5]
>
> [5, 2, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8] (wrong)
>
> [5, 2, 4, 0, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0, 7, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 0, 8, 2, 7, 6, 3, 9, 0]
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9] (right)
>
> [8, 5, 7, 6, 2, 7, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 9]
>
> [1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 9] (wrong)

Basically, how do I get it so that all the arrays will come out ordered in the right way? I'm really not sure where the error is because, comparing it to other pieces of code to do the similar thing, it seems to be consistent.
Thanks

Comment: Don't swap the i-th element with the current min inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This elements swap:

```
if(currentMin != i) {
    int placeholder = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[currentMin];
    numbers[currentMin] = placeholder;
}
```

should be outside the whole inner loop.

Selection sort is a finding minimum element in the remaining part of the array (inner loop) and swapping this minimum with the element in the current position. Thus, there is at most one swap at every outer loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is swapping `i` instead of the `currentMin`

You can amend like so (and also possibly no need for `if(currentMin != i) {`)

```
int placeholder  = numbers[currentMin];  
numbers[currentMin] = numbers[i];
numbers[i] = placeholder;
```